# thematic map: mouseover

Tags: javascript, api

i am generating a chart map like this:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=440x220&cht=t&chco=CBD122&chld=US&chd=s:_&chtm=usa

[image]

does anyone know if there is a feature to do something on mouseover? like have each state turn a different color on mouse over?

Comment: You know you can edit your own questions, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504167/need-a-map-of-the-us-with-states

Comment: Nevermind, you deleted it, good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a response to your last question.  Roll your own.

This is relatively simple.  Grab an available svg map of the [US](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg).  Clean it up to match your theme.  Change fill colors and whatever else.  Add some [javascript](http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/) for the mouseover effect.

This [site](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/interactive-svg-map) may have exactly what you need.  Well presented too.

Comment: thank you very much, i asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504384/svg-how-do-i-do-a-mouse-over-effect

Comment: can u please show me how to do a mouse over effect? like displaying a message or changing color of the state?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a hover effect you can add a simple stylerule e.g

`*:hover { fill: green !important }`

I found the `!important` part to be necessary for most maps on wikipedia. Anyway, I have some examples:

- [World map colorizer](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/mapcolorizer/countries-withname.htm) (press and
  hold mousebutton for a moment on a
  country to show color palette) Full code and other variants can be found [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/mapcolorizer/).
- [Map with zoomed-in-view that follows
  mouse](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/examples/MapWithDynamicMiniView.svg)